# How to measure the asymmetry of data distribution in a convex?

Tags: spatial, uniform-distribution

I have some 2d points data and I generated a convex hull mesh. Looking by eye, it seems that the points are not uniformly distributed inside the convex. I wonder what is the best way to characterize this asymmetry? An example is like this:

data:

{{1.70411, -0.82218}, {1.47802, 0.85122}, {3.19453, 2.18674}, {0.583261, -0.7624}, {1.20318, -0.487035}, {1.0349, -0.087872}, {1.06771, 0.370179}, {0.645045, -0.545495}, {1.42052, 0.839666}, {0.055145, -0.0183668}, {0.43104, 0.29658}, {0.443926, 0.304759}, {4.31065, -0.836811}, {4.12503, 2.28684}}

convex hull mesh:

[image]

Comment: Are you simply looking to measure the degree of general nonuniformity, or are you specifically after something relating to *symmetry*. If symmetry is really the issue, can you be more specific about the sense in which you mean it, given the convex polygonal region is not itself symmetric? [Indeed, I wouldn't think to describe a uniform distribution of points over that figure as "symmetric", even though it's possible to create a set of transformations (interchanges of identically-shaped small interior regions for example) that would leave that uniformity unaltered]

Comment: Depending on your goal & context (you did not tell us), it might be better to model as a spatial point pattern. Look into Ripley K-function?